# Permission Denied for Rails assets directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu, passenger, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've been searching for an answer online for awhile.  I am running an app on Ubuntu/Apache/Passenger.  I'm receiving a "permission denied" error to my assets folder.  My file are located in the home directory.  I run `ls -l` and it returns:

```
drwxrwxr-x 6 root root 4096 Aug 19 01:30 tmp
```

Comment: Hi, the error is the following: ActionView::Template::Error (Permission denied - /home/public_html/events/tmp/cache/assets/CC8):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

I moved my app to var/www then I ran the following:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/appname
```

Answer (score 0):

So the app is called `events` and this folder is owned by `root`? If also `events/config.ru` is owned by `root` then passenger will not start the app as root but usually as `nobody`. Check out http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#user_switching